# Effectiveness of suggested answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, search, autocomplete

Does anybody have some data on how effective the suggested answers are in preventing people from asking duplicate questions?

While some people make an effort to search, some people will click the "Ask Question" button and will start typing their question. To deal with that SE dynamically suggests to users, answers which match the subject of their post.

What % of people click on such answers (obviously it depends on the quality of the suggestion).

Does it actually stop people from posting their questions (that would probably require an A/B test with two pages, one with auto-suggest on and other with off, so that impact can be attributed to auto-suggest only).

Any other related insights or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I've edited your post so that it references Stack Exchange only, as this site is for discussing Stack Exchange and not other sites. However, it's an interesting question and the answers might mean more work should be done on improving the suggestions so +1.

Comment: Related UX question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/effectiveness-of-suggested-answers-on-forums-like-stackexchange-and-others

Comment: You mean "Questions that may already have your answer", don't you? In such case, I don't think such data is available (i.e. when user click a link shown this way and not posting a question as result) but from personal experience here on Meta, many times the relevant questions appear only after posting, under "Related".

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything in the URL for these that would allow easy tracking.

Comment: It is easy to ask a duplicate question - I have, after searching and then when the duplicate is pointed out, it's like doh, the wording is different and it never occurred to me to use that particular wording.. and let's face it, we can't have all the bases covered when searching, there are so many variations of saying the same thing.

Comment: Actually I was showing a friend the site to day and I said, you have to be specific when searching, as it likes the correct spelling for words, not that is something (as English as a first language) that does not bother me.. gave you a vote up for the question